# transfering data from a php script file to another

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

here is my code...

```
loginscript.php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="seelsdb"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="tblteacher"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$uname=$_POST['uname']; 
$pword=$_POST['pword']; 
// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$uname = stripslashes($uname);
$pword = stripslashes($pword);
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($uname);
$pword = mysql_real_escape_string($pword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE teacherEmail='$uname' and teacherPass='$pword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_start();
$_SESSION['loginp']=$pword;
$_SESSION['login']=$uname;
header("location:schedule.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

?>
```

and here is a snippet of schedule.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$uname=$_SESSION['login'];
echo $uname;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body class="body">
<table class="maintable">
<tr valign="top">
<td align="center">
<img src="images/banner.jpg"   />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<!-- this part is for the menu area -->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr valign="top">
<td width="20%">
<!-- this part is for the login part -->
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<!-- i want to display $_SESSION['login'] here -->
WELCOME! $uname 
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

now, how can i get the value of $_SESSION['login'] from loginscript.php and display it in one of the table cells in schedule.php???

i am getting an error that says Notice: Undefined index: login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first, you should start session before headers sent in loginscript.php. Second you should print login like .  In source you should add `session_start();` line to your loginscript.php( this should be the first line) and when printing username in HTML code you should instead of `echo hello $uname` write `<? echo"hello $uname"; ?>`

Comment: sir read the first snippet and the second, i did add a session_start(); or do you mean it should be placed after the <?php line? i am getting an error now which says Notice: Undefined index: login on line 4 and that line is $uname=$_SESSION['login'];

Comment: @PatrickNarcelles please post your edited code to pastebin or here to have a look.

Comment: sir i changed the first part of schedule.php

<?php
session_start();
$uname=$_SESSION['login'];
?>

and i didnt change yet the loginscript.php

Comment: @PatrickNarcelles have you added `session_start();` line in loginscript.php file after `<?php` ? It's important to add this line to your loginscript.php file.

Answer (score 0):

simple, you should print the variable with `PHP`

```
WELCOME! <?php echo $uname; ?>
```

on the other hand, in first file (`loginscript.php`) you should add `session_start()` right before `<?php` because you have `ini_set('display_errors', true);` and that will break your session.

Comment: @jogesh_p did you read his question and code? Please read last 6 lines from second code snippet.

Comment: sir both script are on different files, i removed the first echo in the schedule.php, now it still gives an error which is Notice: Undefined index: login on line 4 which is $uname=$_SESSION['login'];

Comment: Actually it's not even funny. "Programmer" that doesn't know how to use `echo`, hmmmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: sir may i just clarify your answer, what do you mean i should add session_start right before <?php ??

Answer (score 0):

Use;

```
WELCOME! <?php echo $uname; ?>
```

instead